# Drag/pan a bit randomly using Google Maps JS API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am currently using the Google Maps JavaScript API like that:

```
function initMap() {
        var locationRio = {lat: -22.915, lng: -43.197};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 18,
          center: locationRio
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: locationRio,
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        });
      }
```

This will create a map of `Rio de Janeiro` - but I want it to randomly drag/pan the map (a bit, not a lot)

I've tried adding more float numbers next to the latitude and the longitude (for example: `{lat: -22.9159504, lng: -43.1978506}`) but it doesn't make a medium difference (I want it not so big and not so small difference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You coul try using random

```
  function initMap() {
        var random = Math.random( );  
        var lat = -22.915;
        var lng = -43.197; 

        var locationRio = {lat: (lat + random/100), lng: (lng +random/100)};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 18,
          center: locationRio
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: locationRio,
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        });
      }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I always used addition and subtraction and never tried to do division :)

Comment: @gabugu   a random result is tipically a value between 0 and 1 and for a valid lat lng  you must use this value/100  or value/1000 ..  at the equator 1 degree of longitude is about 111000 m so a random of 0.1 ... corresponds to 11100 mt while 0.001 to 111mt  (I hope I explained myself clearly)

Comment: But `random/100` dragged the same distance every 2-3 tries, I changed it to `random/10` and now it is good.. is that a problem?

Comment: no .. the use of /10 or 100  depend of the range you want move the  possible map position .. this happen because your lat lng have only 3 decimal digit  .. try using more